# What do you call a parent with no children?

Tags: database, object

I have some code where the user can delete one child record of a parent record one at a time. I'm detecting when there are no children left. At that point, I'm deleting the parent record as well. When coming up with a name for the variable, I realized I don't know what you call a parent with no children.

Is there a single, accepted name that I haven't heard of (or can't remember)?

Comment: I don't know of one in OO design. In the real world, I'd call a parent with no children left an `EmptyNester` and I like that as a variable name too. :)

Comment: Are you looking for a name taken from the real world? I would probably have some code like `if (parent.children() == 0) parent.delete();` where it wouldn't even need its own variable name.

Comment: Well in a tree it would be a Leaf node?

Comment: @Pharylon Semantically, I'd argue an `EmptyNester` still *has* children, the state of said children has just changed ;)

Comment: Childless or yuppies or perhaps... Leaf or end node...  or ask http://english.stackexchange.com/  or ... DINKs (Dual income no kids?)

Comment: @xQbert Someone already has: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24112/whats-a-good-word-to-describe-adults-who-are-not-yet-parents/169893#169893 . I'd be somewhat inclined towards "barren", but it's a bit of a loaded term.

Comment: Looks like there is no single answer. @Allan, it's funny, I thought about using english.stackexchange.com a few minutes ago, too. That question isn't exactly what I meant because I wanted an object that used to have children, not never had children. I did find the word parphent that seems to have been coined in 2013. My code currently uses `lonelyParent`. My co-worker suggested `orphanedParent`.

Comment: If you're looking for a term that's commonly used among programmers and/or computer scientists, I think there just isn't one, except maybe `leaf node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Leaf**: (**no** children)

**Terminal**: (**never** children)

**Vacant**: (**had** children)

**Orphan**: (**no** parent)

---

Leaf seems pretty standard according to wikipedia. "Terminal Node" on wikipedia will re-direct you to leaf node.

### Vacant node in more detail:

Your orphanage had a child. The child got adopted and left. Your orpahage is now vacant.

### Terminal node in more detail:

Example in OpenGL:

An EBO references a VAO.
A  VAO references a VBO.
A  VBO is raw data and references nothing else.

( **EBO** --> **VAO** --> **VBO** )

Thinking of the VBO as a "terminal node" would make more sense than thinking of it
as a leaf. Because it will not and cannot have children.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common computer science notions of parent: relative/transitive and absolute/non-transitive. One node can be the parent of another (a child). (Hence, object of a transitive "is" or "parents"). A node with no children is a leaf node; a node with children is a parent node. (Hence, object of a non-transitive "is"). Neither of these involve the non-instantaneous notion of ever once having had children, eg as in the real world.

Each node of the type you are describing is during processing (before and after pruning) both a parent and not a parent. So you are using something like the non-instantaneous/real-world third meaning, something like "was a parent but isn't any more". (Think about what you're saying: it's a parent in the sense that it used to be a parent node even though it's not a parent node. So it's a parent ...because... it's not a parent.)

Once it's going to be deleted, how about NoLongerParent? But if you're just using a name for that node for all the processing, and it starts as a non-leaf, why not just Parent?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer. I think everything you say is true. I like the name noLongerParent. I agree that it's current, childless state makes leaf a good name too. But it doesn't convey that it is an object that previously had children. It's clear that there is not an accepted term for this.

Comment: Ah, natural language. Eg I can't see how "no longer a parent" could convey anything *other* than "previously had children (but doesn't now)".

Comment: I just reread my comment, and I agree with you now. I don't know why I said it doesn't convey that it is an object that previously had children.

Comment: It's been years, but I just reread my comment, and I think I was referring leaf. **Leaf** does not convey that it is an object that previously had children.

Comment: A problem with naming programming language things is that variables vary. Lifetime is important. It is not a good idea to give a name that only applies during part of a lifetime. Even a constant's name should make sense while related variables change. Obligatory quote: [“There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things”](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19836/has-phil-karlton-ever-said-there-are-only-two-hard-things-in-computer-science)

Comment: Agreed. In this case I remember it being a boolean variable, so I was looking for something like isNoLongerParent.